# Есть ли возможность использовать if else в templateLayoutFactory

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Есть примерно такой (нерабочий) шаблон вывода balloon:

```
BalloonLayout = ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass(
  "<div class='my-hint'>" +
    "<div class='title'>{{ properties.company }}</div>" +
    '{% if options.shop == YES %}да' +
    '{% else %}нет{% endif %}' +
    '</div>' +
  "</div>" , {
```

Задача проверять содержимое options.shop и выводить соответствующую надпись "да" или "нет". Буду благодарен любым подсказкам.

https://jsbin.com/kemepucezo/edit?html,js,output - тестовый прототип

Comment: А можете оформить минимальный рабочий пример кода на jsbin.com или любой другой песочнице для тестов? Непонятен механизм добавления объектов и почему нельзя параметр сразу на русском в объекты внедрять?

Comment: Да, конечно.

https://jsbin.com/kemepucezo/edit?html,js,output

По второму вопросу: хочется понять функционал взаимодействия с данными в объектах и возможность применения условий к ним.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможность есть, но по какой-то причине сейчас **IF** не срабатывает с **options**.

Можно перенести опции объектов в свойства, а в проверке прописать **properties.salon == "YES"**. Так итоговое **da** будет прорастать в балун только при наличии нужного значения в поле **salon**.

Обратите внимание **YES** в этом случае заключать в кавычки нужно и в проверочной строке, поскольку в свойствах – строковое значение.

Вот ваши изменённый пример:
https://jsbin.com/sorilif/edit?js,output

Comment: Большое спасибо за исчерпывающий ответ!